# React useState async setter doesn't update value passed as props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this component in my React project -

```
const ViewPost = (props: Props) => {
  const [listingData, setListingData] = useState<any>({})
  const [auctionData, setAuctionData] = useState<any>({})

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.listingId) {
      getListingData()
    }
  }, [props.listingId])

  const getListingData = async () => {
    const { data } = await getListingById(props.listingId)
    setListingData(data?.data)

    if (data.data.isTimedAuction) {
      auctions(data.data.auctionId)
    }
  }

  const auctions = async (auctionId: any) => {
    const auction = await getAuctions(auctionId)
    console.log('auction', auction.data)
    setAuctionData(auction.data)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <div className={classes.viewPostPage}>
        <div className={classes.bodyContainer}>
     
            <Details
              data={listingData as any}
              updateListing={getListingData}
              auctionData={auctionData}
            />
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default ViewPost
```

Basically, I'm getting data from an API and assigning it to `auctionData`.

`console.log(auction.data)` shows me the desired result but when I pass `auctionData` as props into `Details` I get an empty object which leads to a lot of issues, since `useState` is async.

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: `auctionData` always starts out as an empty object. Your `Details` component needs to be able to handle that. Otherwise, I'd initialise `auctionData` as `null` or `undefined` and use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) to decide _when_ to render `Details`

Comment: Can I use refs here?

Answer (score 0):

```
const [auctionData, setAuctionData] = useState<any>({})
```

your default value is an empty object, that causes the problems.

should set `null` or `undefined` as default value, and hide the `Details` when not have the data.

Answer (score 0):

Use loading state. Once data is fully fetched from api then pass to child component. I think what is happeing here is that child component is called with empty state variable while data is still being fetched.

```
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)
    const getListingData = async () => {
    const { data } = await getListingById(props.listingId)
                          .then((data) => {setListingData(data)})
                          .then((data) => {
                             setTimeout(() => {
                                  setIsLoading(false)
                             }, 1000)
                           })

    if (data.data.isTimedAuction) {
      auctions(data.data.auctionId)
    }
  }
```

and then return

```
  if (isLoading) {
        return (
            <div>
                Loading...
            </div>
        )
    }

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <div className={classes.viewPostPage}>
        <div className={classes.bodyContainer}>
     
            <Details
              data={listingData as any}
              updateListing={getListingData}
              auctionData={auctionData}
            />
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```