# Passing data to Carousel component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Having problems with populating Carousel component with data from API. API is tested and returns data correctly. Console.log(items) at line 52 returns undefined but console.log(res.data) at line 54 returns the data correctly. In otherwords, how do I return data from APIGet so tha const slides can map it correctly:

```
const items = null;

APIGet(resource, params)
.then((res) => {
    setData(res.data)
    console.log(res.data); //works
})
console.log(items); // null
```

This is likely irrelevant but the full code nonetheless:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
    Carousel,
    CarouselItem,
    CarouselControl,
    CarouselIndicators,
} from "reactstrap";

import { APIGet } from '../API.js';
import { Col, Container, Row } from "reactstrap";

function PromotionalCarousel() {

    function CarouselComponent() {

        const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(0);
        const [animating, setAnimating] = useState(false);

        function onExiting() {
            setAnimating(true);
        }

        function onExited() {
            setAnimating(false);
        }

        function next() {
            if (animating) return;
            const nextIndex = activeIndex === items.length - 1 ? 0 : activeIndex + 1;
            setActiveIndex(nextIndex);
        }

        function previous() {
            if (animating) return;
            const nextIndex = activeIndex === 0 ? items.length - 1 : activeIndex - 1;
            setActiveIndex(nextIndex);
        }

        function goToIndex(newIndex) {
            if (animating) return;
            setActiveIndex(newIndex);
        }

        const resource = 'search';
        const params = { 'limit': '3' };

        const [items, setData] = useState()

        APIGet(resource, params)
        .then((res) => {
            setData(res.data)
            console.log(res.data);
        })
        console.log(items);

        const slides = items.map((item) => {
        return (
            <CarouselItem
                tag="div"
                key={item.id}
                onExiting={onExiting}
                onExited={onExited}
            >
                <img alt='carouselimg' className="position-absolute carousel_img" src={item.ThumbImageURL} />
                <Container className="carousel_content">
                    <Row>
                        <div className="py-5">
                            <Col className="position-relative text_white">
                                <div className="pt-5 font_20px">
                                    {item.Title}
                                </div>
                            </Col>
                        </div>
                    </Row>
                </Container>
            </CarouselItem>
            );
        });

        return (
        <div>
            <Carousel className="carousel_img" activeIndex={activeIndex} next={next} previous={previous}>
                {slides}
                    <div className='d-flex justify-content-end carousel_right'>
                        <CarouselIndicators items={items} activeIndex={activeIndex} onClickHandler={goToIndex} />
                        <CarouselControl direction="prev" directionText="Previous" onClickHandler={previous} />
                        <CarouselControl direction="next" directionText="Next" onClickHandler={next} />
                    </div>
            </Carousel>
        </div>
        );
    }

    return (
        <CarouselComponent />
    );

};

export default PromotionalCarousel;
```

Comment: console.log(items) show empty because this line gets called while data is still being fetched from API. Try to render after data is fetched. You can look this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/71761994/13405106

Comment: @MUsama thank you, figured out it was something like that (updated question) I will try immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Use async await to wait until you get the data. It will make the api call asynchronous instead of synchronous.

```
const getData = async () => { 
const { data } = await APIGet(resource, params)
        .then((res) => {
            setData(res.data)
            console.log(res.data);
        })
}
```